# Android CheckedTextView - Set checkMark dynamically

Tags: android, checkmark, checkedtextview

Given this XML property of the CheckedTextView's checkMark:

```
android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
```

How can you set the checkMark property dynamically (i.e. from code)?
Does Android have any documentation on this?

**Using:** Android 1.5

**Note:**
I am building a regular jar library that does not have any access to android XML resource files or drawables so everything has to be created programatically.

Answer (score 3):

From the API doc of `CheckedTextView`, it sounds like the two [`setCheckMarkDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html#setCheckMarkDrawable%28int%29) methods would do the job?

You just need to pass in a `StateListDrawable`.